# Rails object will not be created

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.11

Main question: what could cause Rails to send me the index page for an object type after trying to create a new object of that type?  No errors produced, no success message, no new entries in the database

I used `ruby script/generate scaffold poster owner_id:integer event_id:integer` to create a standard scaffold, then ran `rake db:migrate`.  Without changing any files, I tried to create a new poster object, and it sent me to /posters rather than /posters/show/1, as it's supposed to do.

**Other information which may be of help:**

There are other object types already in place on the server.  This problem originally cropped up when I was trying to have the poster belong_to :owner and belong_to :event.

If the information was getting to the model to be validated, it would return an error blank required entries.  If I enter the data manually into the MySQL database, it shows up in the index page, and can be edited (and saved) without issue.  Because of that, I think that the issue is either in the controller file or the database itself, but nothing raised a red flag when I looked through.

I have minimal (4 weeks of a class) experience with Rails, and have been stuck on this for three days now.

**routes.rb:** (commented lines stripped)

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :posters
  map.resources :place_informations
  map.resources :building_polygon_coordinates
  map.resources :alternate_names
  map.resources :events
  map.resources :hours_listings
  map.resources :locations

  map.connect 'json/buildings', :controller => 'json', :action => 'buildings'
  map.resources :users
  map.resources :buildings

  map.root :controller => "home"

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

**Applicable part of development.log:** (the very end; just the attempt to create a new poster; SQL calls stripped out)

```
Processing PostersController#index (for <my IP address> at 2011-05-26 20:32:44) [GET]
~~ SQL stuff, call timings ~~~
Rendering template within layouts/posters
Rendering posters/index
~~ SQL stuff, call timings ~~~


Processing PostersController#new (for <my IP address> at 2011-05-26 20:32:48) [GET]
~~ SQL stuff, call timings ~~~
Rendering template within layouts/posters
Rendering posters/new
~~ SQL stuff, call timings ~~~



Processing PostersController#index (for <my IP address> at 2011-05-26 20:32:56) [GET]
~~ SQL stuff, call timings ~~~
Rendering template within layouts/posters
Rendering posters/index
~~ SQL stuff, call timings ~~~
```

It *is* "get index, get new, get index"
It should be* "get index, get new, post create, get show, get index"

Comment: Is your form issuing a GET request, by chance? You could check this by looking at the output of your server as you press the submit button.

Comment: @Ryan: I... embarrassingly don't know how to do that.  The server's running on Bluehost, so I don't have direct access to the console, and I don't know how to view the output via SSH. ><

Comment: Look in your log file..there must be some way to access it? If not, then hack it out by making a temporary page and using <%= `tail log/development.log` %> :) (note that the *tail log/development.log* should be surrounded with "backticks". It is not displaying above because StackOverflow is using the backtick for code formatting...)

Comment: Oh, that log.  I figured he meant something different. ><  I'll add it to the question info.

Comment: Can you post us the form-tag line of the view? (not the whole view, just the line that generates the form-tag). I'm asking because it does sound like something's not right in how the form is posting and if it is doing it as a GET instead of a POST, then you will see this kind of thing happening.

Comment: `<% form_for @poster, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>`

Is that the line you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed.

The DirectorySlash toggle in Apache had to be set to "Off".  I'm not sure why that affected it in the way that it did, but the issue was resolved after adding the line `DirectorySlash Off` to ".htaccess".